# How to grab Excel value based on first iteration of another value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
Event City  | Sale Date
Los Angeles | 6/19/18
Los Angeles | 6/25/18
Los Angeles | 6/29/18
Phoenix     | 6/20/18
Phoenix     | 6/27/18
Phoenix     | 7/14/18
```

I need to figure out how to return, using a formula, the earliest Sale Date using the Event City.

For instance, using a formula I need to be able to specify "Los Angeles" and have it return "6/18/18".

I'm not even sure where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Office 365/Office 2019, the `MINIFS` function is what you are looking for. See here for more info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599

`=MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,E4)`

Where `B2:B7` is your range of sale dates, `A2:A7` is your range of cities, and `E4` is the city name you are looking up.

### [image]

If you are on an older version of Office, use the following array formula instead - be sure to enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

`=MIN(IF(A2:A7=E4,B2:B7))`